# Need code to remove line from all sheets in Google sheet file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get lines to delete when they are marked delivered on the "MANAGERS" page.

(For Exmaple, the 1990 Subuaru Sh*$%box is "delivered" to a customer, and it is marked so in column "T" on the Managers page. That row #3 is then deleted automatically from each sheet except first sheet and the last three.)
Do I have to call them out by name in the code, or is there a way to single them out?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Dv0D2eHxtQ4LpVsULyjWu942YSqgu_sYwVQ-IOTm80/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

About `except first sheet and the last three`, in this case, if these sheet names are constant, how about running the script by checking the sheet names? Because, when the order of sheets is changed, if the sheet index is used, the unexpected result occurs. I'm worried about this.

If the sheet names of the excluding sheet are used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const excludeSheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you don't want to delete rows.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const baseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MANAGERS");
  const rows = baseSheet.getRange("T2:T" + baseSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("DELIVERED").findAll().map(r => r.getRow()).reverse();
  if (rows.length == 0) return;
  ss.getSheets().forEach(s => {
    if (!excludeSheets.includes(s.getSheetName())) {
      rows.forEach(row => s.deleteRow(row));
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the value of `DELIVERED` is searched from the column "T" of "MANAGERS" sheet using TextFinder. And, when the value is found, the same row numbers are deleted from each sheet except for the sheet names of `excludeSheets`.

#### Note:

- From `That row #3 is then deleted automatically from each sheet except first sheet and the last three.)`, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seemed that the sheet names of the first sheet and the last three are `const excludeSheets = ["NAVIGATION", "Outside Services ", "Internal Phone Log", "SOLD VEHICLES"];`. But, please confirm your sheet names again. Because, for example, the sheet name of `"Outside Services "` has a space in the sheet name. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [deleteRow(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)

Comment: It does create an unexpected problem though.

Comment: When a column is Magically Deleted (sorry for the Lucky Charms jingle that just ran through my head), it screws up the formulas for the rest of the sheets. Any way to adjust for that?

Comment: @Uebelhor Detail Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new issue of `it screws up the formulas for the rest of the sheets.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to think of it by correctly understanding your new issue. I deeply apologize that I try to correctly understand your new issue.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion.I get a #ref error because the source for the formula has been deleted by the script. Thereby screwing up the other formulas.

Comment: @Uebelhor Detail Thank you for replying. About `I get a #ref error because the source for the formula has been deleted by the script. Thereby screwing up the other formulas.`, unfortunately, I cannot still understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to confirm it.